# What is the difference between emma.jar ,emma_ant.jar and emma_device.jar?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, emma

Now ,I have a test project need using emma.

But when I open the `"$ANDROID_HOME/sdk/tools/lib"` path, I found three emma*.jar.

It's *emma.jar*, *emma_ant.jar*, *emma_device.jar*.

But anybody can tell me what's there difference ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer, about two of the three jars :

> **emma.jar** Contains the implementation of EMMA core components command
>   line tools, and EMMA runtime classes (EMMA classes that are needed by
>   Java application code that has been instrumented for coverage).
>
> **emma_ant.jar** Contains the implementation of EMMA ANT tasks (this
>   archive depends on emma.jar and does not overlap with it in content).

See [Emma Reference Manual](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference_single/reference.html)

Comment: ok,but what about the emma_device.jar? I found these jars in my android sdk.